# Relative path in absolute URI in hadoop hive shell

Tags: hadoop, hive

When I am trying to execute the **.hql** file from a shell prompt I am getting the following error. Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI: hdfs://localhost:9000./=/usr/local/hadoop/usr/Move

**Query.hql** contains:

```sql
create table if not exists MOVE(value string) location '${hiveconf:Move_Path}';
```

In the shell prompt I using this command to execute the file:

```
$ HIVE_HOME/bin/hive  -hiveconf Move_Path =/usr/POC/Move -f /home/ram/Source_Files/Source_code/Query.hql
```

I'm unsure about what exactly I need pass to the *"Move_Path"* argument - presently I am setting it as *"/usr/POC/Move"* - is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space (that should be removed) between Move_Path and =/usr/POC/Move. Try this it will work:

```
$HIVE_HOME/bin/hive -hiveconf Move_Path=/usr/POC/Move -f /home/ram/Source_Files/Source_code/Query.hql
```